# How is the BIOS name of a bootable hard drive created (and can it be changed)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have an external hard drive with three partitions: an EFI partition, and two Linux install partitions.

When I plug the hard drive into my computer and enter the boot menu to boot into my portable installs, the hard drive shows up in the list as expected, but its name is not what I anticipated (see picture).

```
 USB1 - Ubuntu(ST1000LX015-107172 0)
```

Does anyone know what actually named the drive like this (I know it's the name of the first OS I installed, Ubuntu, with the firmware name of the hard drive in parentheses).

Secondly, is there a way to change this name?

[image]

Comment: It is common for the drive to be named by its full model number, which is what you're seeing. I would guess that at the BIOS level the system is pulling the the name from the drive's firmware. If the drive allows modifying these values you may find this in a utility published by the manufacturer. Once you're into the OS you can probably find some utility to change the name the OS uses without modifying the drive firmware.

Comment: Just because it's a name shown in the BIOS, don't call it what you called it in your title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> “…with the firmware name of the hard drive in parentheses…”

Nope. That is not firmware name. That is the drive model number.

That name can be distilled to simply ST1000LX015 which basically means your system sees `USB1` as having an Ubuntu install available on a drive with the model number ST1000LX015 which is a [Seagate ST1000LX015 FireCuda](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/seagate-laptop-fam/laptop-sshd/en-us/docs/100802299c.pdf).

The 1U7172 appended to it is just the revision number for the drive itself. Meaning the drive model number is ST1000LX015 with a revision number of 1U7172.

As to how that can be changed? It all depends on the USB-to-SATA bridge board in the USB enclosure and I honestly don’t think what you want to do can be done.

Some external USB enclosures have USB-to-SATA bridge boards that simply send their own generic device names for *any* drive they are hooked up to. In this case it seems the USB-to-SATA bridge board is just passing through the drive model name.

So I don’t know if it is possible to change that “name” to anything else nor am I familiar with an USB-to-SATA bridge boards that allow for custom naming.

Comment: The `Ubuntu` (volume label) is probably alterable with e.g. `e2label` from `e2fsprogs` for ext2/3/4 partitions, and in similar manner for a selection of `dosfstools`, `exfat-utils`, `mtools`, `ntfs-3g`, `udftools` and probably more.

Comment: So just some clarification on the "Ubuntu" part, is that coming from the OS that the BIOS sees in the first partition after the EFI partition? I believe the volume label is "ubuntu-portable" so I don't think that it comes from that.